# Convert pandas selected columns into a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 columns and N rows. I want to select two columns from my data frame and put them into a NumPy 2D array with dimensions (N, 2). How to do that?

Comment: `df[['A','B']].to_numpy()`

Answer (score 9):

There is a way to convert a dataframe to a numpy array: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html

You could just select the columns you want:

```
df[['Col1','Col2']].to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

I will be simulating your problem to answer this question

I am first creating a data frame with 10 columns and 50 rows :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low = 1 , high = 30 , size = (50 ,10)) , columns = ['a' , 'b' ,'c' ,'d' ,'e' ,'f' ,'g' ,'h' ,'i' ,'j'])
```

Now I will create an numpy array of size (50,2) by taking two columns from my dataframe df :

```
a = np.array(df[['a' ,'b']])
```

Now checking the shape of the numpy array 'a' to confirm your solution :

```
a.shape
```

The output for the above code will be (50,2)

Happy coding :)